# Does there exist a plane curve such that it has the heart curve as catacaustic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, algebraic-curves

Given a curve $C$ and a fixed point $L$ (the light source), the catacaustic of $C$ with respect to $L$ is the envelope of light rays coming from $L$ and reflected from the curve $C$.

The catacaustic may or may not form a curve, but it sometimes does. For example, the cardioid and nephroid are both catacaustics of the circle, and the nephroid is a catacaustic of the cardioid.

My question is, is there a plane curve $C$, such that it has the heart curve $(x^2+y^2-1)^3 = x^2y^3$ as the catacaustic, for some properly chosen light source? And is there a computational approach so that one can find it?

The heart curve: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html

Comment: Nice Valentine's Day question :)

Comment: Norbert Hungerbühler's paper [The Inverse Caustic Problem](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2020.1722019) (*Amer. Math. Monthly* 127 (2020), 387-400) seems relevant, but I don't know if it directly answers the question.

Comment: the cardioid also has the form of a heart, doesn't it?